# Android handle click event late

Tags: android, button, onclick, delay, onclicklistener

I am writing a rather simple application in Android, most of the code is handling nice animations to make it look good.

My problem is that sometimes a button is clicked, but the related onClick() from the onClick listener is called only after another button is clicked.

it seams that Android is "buffering" the events and handling them in groups, rather then handling them at the time they were generated.

Did anyone of you got this problem before, or can suggest resolution?

I am not sure if it is important,  but I generally use anonymous objects as my listeners, it makes more sense to me.

```
        score.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    score.setClickable(true);
    score.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            soundEffect.soundForId(SoundEffect.DELETE_SOUND);
            player.setToRmove(true);

                            //Toggle trash button to replace the score button and
                            // identify for the user that this player is due to be deleted
            score.setVisibility(GONE);
            score.setClickable(false);
            trashButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            trashButton.setClickable(true);
            trashButton.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once in a project. I was playing a shoot sound which is about 2-3 sec long, but if someone tap it frequently, it grouped the events. I solve that problem by disabling the shoot button for 2 second after each time it pressed. Hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this logically.  Which of the following scenarios is more likely?

Android has some code to monitor how quickly your UI generates events.  If it sees that you are generating them quickly enough, it starts to batch them together.  Questions.  What does quickly mean?  What assumptions need to be made?  Why would I write such an insane piece of code?

Or

Since instances of your anonymous inner classes are created when the event is raised and those instances are executed on a single thread, you main UI thread, Android places messages to execute those instances onto the thread's message queue.  Questions?

If you have code running on your main thread that is anything other than trivial and generally not related to updating the UI, then use another thread, e.g. AsyncTask, to execute the code.  For something taking 2-3 seconds, you should definitely do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such "grouping" of events. Of course events are processed from a queue, and as Simon suggested, you probably do too much on the UI-thread at some point and you block it.